# php warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli

Tags: php, mysqli

I am attempting a connection to a sql db via php and keep getting an error I can't figure out.  I can connect with another debug scripts with no errors.  I get my connection and pull my data but pulls an error at the end.

```
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","dbname");
 
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
 
// This SQL statement selects ALL from the table 'Locations'
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Locations";
 
// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();
 
    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object())
    {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }
 
    // Finally, encode the array to JSON and output the results
    echo json_encode($resultArray);
}
 
// Close connections
mysqli_close($result);
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Brings this out

> [{"Name":"Apple","Address":"1 Infinity Loop Cupertino, CA","Latitude":"37.331741","Longitude":"-122.030333"},{"Name":"Googleplex","Address":"1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy, Mountain View, CA","Latitude":"37.421999","Longitude":"-122.083954"}]
>
> Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given in /home/jfletch/public_html/appone/connect.php on line 36

Comment: connection is closed at end of script so its not even required in your code, as its closed anyways...

Comment: Simply, you don't close the query or "result." Only the connection should be closed, if anything.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
mysqli_close($result);
```

The line above is incorrect. You only need to call `mysqli_close()` once (if at all since, as pointed out in the comments, the connection is closed at the end of the execution of your script) and the parameter should be your link identifier, not your query resource.

Remove it.

Comment: Be sure your script ends and you are not making connections in a loop.  No answers here discuss mysqli_free_result($result); and then  mysqli_close($conn);  This is almost certainly what the OP intentended, but there might have been a copy and paste from the same source for both lines .;)

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally we FREE the result, and CLOSE the connection.  It looks like both those lines were copied from the same source during a copy/paste.
So the first mysqli_close does have a bad parameter.

You want mysqli_free_result($result); there instead.

Leaving aside that it is supposedly not necessary if the script ends. It cannot hurt. There may be a great many connections before the script ends if you do not re-use connections.